# Minimizing amount of if/else if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm currently programming a speech tool in a project at my university. I got the advice to cut the amount of if/else if statements, but i can't think about another way solving it except maybe switch/case.

Every Voice Output is different and the Coroutines need different Paramaters based on the train type. So i don't know how to simplify those. Are there special methods / best practices in C# to solve problems like this?

The Application is developed in Unity wiht the Microsoft Speech API

So the statements are like

```
if (spokenText.IndexOf("Ticket") > 0)
        // Voice Output

else if (spokenText.IndexOf("Wo") > 0)
    {
        if (spokenText.IndexOf("Bahn") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("Zug") > 0)
        {
            //Ask for Train
        }
        else if (spokenText.IndexOf("nächste") > 0 && (spokenText.IndexOf("RE") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("S-Bahn") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("ICE") > 0) || spokenText.IndexOf(" S ") > 0
            || spokenText.IndexOf("IC") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("EC") > 0)
        {

            if (spokenText.IndexOf("ICE") > 0)
            {
                //Start Coroutine
            }
            else if (spokenText.IndexOf("EC") > 0)
            {
               // Start Coroutine with different Parameter
            }
            else if (spokenText.IndexOf("IC") > 0)
            {
            //Start Coroutine with different Parameter
            }
        }
        else
            // Voice output
    }
    else if (spokenText.IndexOf("Wann") > 0)
    {
        if ((spokenText.IndexOf("Zug") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("Bahn") > 0) && spokenText.IndexOf("nächste") > 0 && spokenText.IndexOf("nach") > 0)
        {
            // Coroutine
        }
        else if (spokenText.IndexOf("Zug") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("Bahn") > 0)
        {
            // Voice output
        }

        else if (spokenText.IndexOf("nächste") > 0 && (spokenText.IndexOf("RE") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("S-Bahn") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("ICE") > 0) || spokenText.IndexOf(" S ") > 0
            || spokenText.IndexOf("IC") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("EC") > 0)
        {

            if (spokenText.IndexOf("ICE") > 0)
            {

               // Coroutine
            }
            else if (spokenText.IndexOf("EC") > 0)
            {
              //Coroutine
            }
            else if (spokenText.IndexOf("IC") > 0)
            {
              //Coroutine
            }
        }
        else
            //Voice Output

    }
    else if (spokenText.IndexOf("Barrierefrei") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("Aufzug") > 0 || spokenText.IndexOf("Rolltreppe") > 0)
    {
        //Coroutine
    }
    else {
        //Voice Output
    }
}
```

edit: added first if statement

Comment: Does your original code start with `else if`?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a [codereview.se]

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not asking for a code review, but how to avoid such long if/ else statements

Comment: your code cyclomatic complexity is too high currently

Comment: @LukasS As Daniel suggested, if your code works, you should ask that question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @LukasS your code currently works. stackoverflow is for code that doesn't work.

Comment: "stackoverflow is for code that doesn't work" ? Nice. As for question, try to reformat if-elses and go through all logic. Probably you can find some common parts and make external methods and decrease complexity. Try to use LINQ to make call more clear. Good luck.

Comment: First easy simplification: replace all the calls to .IndexOf("someString")>0 with .Contains("SomeString"). Not such a big difference, but it simplify reading that (too much complicated) code

Comment: Maybe you could consider a small lexical parser so you could ask for a true/false against an expression like "Wo/(Bahn|Zug)",

Answer (score 0):

It is not efficient to call IndexOf on the same string so many times. You could split the string to tokens, and use `Dictionary<string, Action>` to call a method for each token, something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sc = new SomeClass();

        sc.ProcessTokens("aa bb");
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

    private int someContext = 0;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        actions["aa"] = DoA;
        actions["bb"] = DoB;
    }

    public void ProcessTokens(string tokens)
    {
        foreach (var token in tokens.Split(' '))
            actions[token]();
    }

    private void DoA()
    {
        someContext++;
        Console.Write("A" + someContext.ToString());
    }

    private void DoB()
    {
        someContext++;
        Console.Write("B" + someContext.ToString());
    }
```

So instead of thousands if-else-if you have hundreds of methods that you call one by one, and in the same class keep track of the context.

Comment: That seems promising in order to simplify OP code, but actually your code has different behavior: IndexOf match substrings, your suggested code doesn't, (maybe it's a better choice), and ProcessTokens calls multiple Action, while OP code just call one (this also can be something good or not, it depends on requirements)

Answer (score 0):

You have too many unrelated items in one category.  Split options into small groups like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum MODE
        {
            GERMAN, 
            TICKET,
            WANN, 
            WO,
        }
        enum COROUTINE
        {
            ICE,
            EC,
            IC,
            BARRIEREFREI,
            AUFZUG,
            ROLLTREPPE,
            ZUG,
            BAHN,
            NÄCHSTE
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MODE mode = MODE.TICKET;
            COROUTINE coroutine =   COROUTINE.IC;
            string language = "nächste";

            switch (mode)
            {
                case MODE.GERMAN :
                    switch (language)
                    {
                        case "Barrierefrei" :
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.BARRIEREFREI);
                            break;
                        case "Aufzug":
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.AUFZUG);
                            break;
                        case "Rolltreppe":
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.ROLLTREPPE);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MODE.TICKET:
                    Voice();
                    break;
                case MODE.WANN:
                    switch (language)
                    {
                        case "Zug":
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.ZUG);
                            break;
                        case "Bahn":
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.BAHN);
                            break;
                        case "NÄCHSTE":
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.NÄCHSTE);
                            break;
                        default :
                            Voice();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MODE.WO:
                    switch (coroutine)
                    {
                        case  COROUTINE.EC :
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.EC);
                            break;
                        case COROUTINE.ICE:
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.ICE);
                            break;
                        case COROUTINE.IC :
                            Coroutine(COROUTINE.IC);
                            break;
                        default :
                            Train();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default :
                    Voice();
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void Coroutine(COROUTINE parameter)
        {
        }
        static void Voice()
        {
        }
        static void Train()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of observations. Your method is too long and is therefore susceptible to errors. I follow a personal rule to have a method which doesnt require scrolling.

Secondly, the number of if/else statements generally follows a [Strategy pattern](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776819/Strategy-Pattern-Csharp).

SpokenTextStrategy (or Stragtegies) can be like TicketStrategy, WoStrategy, WannStrategy.

Also, you can encapsulate this in one method:
    enum SomeTextCheck { ICE, EC, IC };

```
if (spokenText.IndexOf("ICE") > 0)
{
    // Coroutine
}

else if (spokenText.IndexOf("EC") > 0)
{
    //Coroutine
}

else if (spokenText.IndexOf("IC") > 0)
{
 //Coroutine
}
```